# Convert Javascript object to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

OK, so I'm facing this challenge...

**Here's how javascript console *(in Chrome)* prints my object :**

[image]

**And here's what I'd like to do :**

```
var items = [
    { 
        text: "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106307/",
        children: [
             { text: "Director", children: [ { text: "Emir Kusturica" } ] },
             { text: "Title", children: [ { text: "Arizona Dream" } ] }
        ]
    },
    { 
        text: "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110074/",
        children: [
             { text: "Director", children: [ { text: "Joel Coen" }, { text: "Ethan Coen"} ] },
             { text: "Title", children: [ { text:"The Hudsucker Proxy" } ] }
        ]
    }
    // and so on..
];
```

How can I do that? Any ideas/pointers to help me get there?

It should definitely be rather simple, but Javascript is definitely *not* my thing at all...

---

**P.S.** This whole object thing is created after a `$.parseJSON(myJson)` command - now, don't ask me why it's not converted to a simple nested array and it turns into an object instead... I wish I knew... *(not that it'd have the desired structure, but at least it would make more sense)*

---

**UPDATE:**

**OK, and - in case it is helpful - here's my original Json :**

```
{
    "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0106307\/": {
        "Title": "Arizona Dream",
        "Year": null,
        "Director": "Emir Kusturica"
    },
    "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0112883\/?ref_=tt_rec_tt": {
        "Title": "Don Juan de Marco",
        "Year": null,
        "Director": "Jeremy Leven"
    },
    "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0106387\/?ref_=tt_rec_tt": {
        "Title": "Benny & Joon",
        "Year": null,
        "Director": "Jeremiah S. Chechik"
    },
    "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0099487\/?ref_=tt_rec_tt": {
        "Title": "\u039f \u03a8\u03b1\u03bb\u03b9\u03b4\u03bf\u03c7\u03ad\u03c1\u03b7\u03c2",
        "Year": null,
        "Director": "Tim Burton"
    },
    "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0354899\/?ref_=tt_rec_tt": {
        "Title": "La science des r\u00eaves",
        "Year": null,
        "Director": "Michel Gondry"
    },
    "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0110074\/?ref_=tt_rec_tt": {
        "Title": "The Hudsucker Proxy",
        "Year": null,
        "Director": [
            "Joel Coen",
            "Ethan Coen"
        ]
    }
}
```

**P.S. (2)** What I'm actually trying to do is to simply represent a Json object as a tree using [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo), and pushing myself to achieve its desired structure.

Answer (score 1):

In ES5 (so will need a shim if supporting IE 8):

```
function transformToTextNodeTree(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    var result = { text: key };
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) {
        result.children = obj[key].map(transformToTextNodeTree);
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && !(obj[key] == null)) {
      result.children = transformToTextNodeTree(obj[key]);
    } else {
      result.children = [createTextNode(obj[key])];
    }
    return result;
  })
}

function createTextNode(val) {
  return { text: val };
}
```

#### So what is it doing?

First, we create an array of all of the `ownProperties` of the object being passed in using `Object.keys`. We then `map` over the resulting array of `key` values and transform them into objects in the form `{text, [...children]}`.

The actual guts of our mapping function is a recursive function (it calls itself when it encounters an array or an object) that maps the key to the `text` field of the resulting object, and maps any children to the `children` field (and, as noted before, it does this recursively).

Comment: I tried a `var items = transformToTextNodeTree($.parseJSON(myJson));` and it throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object` error... Any ideas? (The error is pointing to the `Object.keys(obj)` part.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon - I was not handling `null` - that is now fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I believe json is built into javascript. You should be able to say:

```
var object = eval("<jsoncode>");
```

where < jsoncode> is the string version of your json

It is possible that I am reading your problem wrong so please give feedback

Answer (score 0):

After you parse JSON, you can try this:

```
var movieArr = [];
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var movie = {
        text: index,
        children: [
            { text: "Director", children: [ { text: value.Director } ] },
            { text: "Title", children: [ { text: value.Title } ] }
        ]
    };   
    arr.push(movie)
});
```

Comment: The sub-fields will *not* necessarily be `Director` and `Title`. There may many different ones, and with infinite nesting. So, this is obviously a too localized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// json - source JSON;
var result = [];
for (var url in json) {
    var el = json[url];
    var kids = [];
    for (var prop in el) {
        var v = el[prop];
        if (!v.length) v = [v];
        var subkids = [];
        for (var i in v) subkids.push({text: v[i]});
        kids.push({text: prop, children: subkids});
    }
    result.push({text: url, children: kids});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**OK, and here's how I've managed to do it** - inspired by your answers :-)

```
function convertJson(node)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(node, function(key,value)
        {   
            var ch;

            if (($.type(value)!=="string")&&(value!=null)) ch = convertJson(value);
            else ch = [ { text: value }];

            var item =
            {
                text: key,
                children: ch

            };
            result.push(item);
        }
    )

    return result;
}
```

And yep, it works!